# Condition not working If statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

```
function ch(x, y) {
    var h = 'OFF';
    document.getElementsByName("ch_u").item(x).innerHTML = "<img src='image/loader.gif' align='absmiddle'>";

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            var c = document.getElementsByName("ch_u").item(x).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if (c == h) {
                alert("1");
            } else {
                document.write(c, h);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "check.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send('y=' + y);
}
```

Always goes to ELSE ,Although (c&h) value is OFF because print (c&h) is OFF in else
I think that a problem in (if)??

Comment: Are you sure they are exactly the same? No white-space around it? What does `xmlhttp.responseText` return?

Comment: Try to log the value of `c` to see if it is really what you expect it to be

Comment: Syjin,value in else is same

Comment: @user3001104: If they were the same, then it would follow the `if` branch, not the `else` branch. Full stop. Therefore, they *are* different, and you have to figure out how and why.

Comment: Add `console.log(c, h);` before your IF statement and make sure both are identical in the log. Your console should display `"OFF", "OFF"`. As @putvande mentioned, "OFF" isnt the same as " OFF", "OFF " or " OFF ".

Comment: I 'm pretty sure that there is no bug haunting the `if` statement.

Comment: @user3001104: Also, using `document.write` in an asynchronous callback is a bad idea. When used after the main parsing of the page is complete, `document.write` does an implied `document.open`, which wipes out the content of the page and starts fresh.

Comment: James, yes display OFF OFF

Comment: @cgoasduff very sensibly suggests (though he doesn't have the rep to comment himself): "Don't really have an answer as such, but in your case I would debug using firebug on Firefox and put breakpoints in your function and see what the code do." Of course chrome and others have debugging tools too.

Comment: As a note when I want to check values like this for whitespace I generally will tend to output delimiters so it is clear where the string is starting and ending. eg `console.log('|'+c+'|')`. Otherwise the output is likely going to have whitespace around it anyway causing it to be unclear whether your original string has whitespace or not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sorry, missed the question. Try to change alert('1') to alert(h).
I think that h in your callback function is not the same, as h in function ch.

Comment: Try to `alert(h);` in your callback function, i think it shall be undefined. If it, you must place `var h = 'OFF';` after `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {`

Comment: Pragmatist ,can't print "1" how print "h"; print h&c true

Comment: alert(h); in callback function, out of `if` statement

Comment: `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
alert(h);
            var c = document.getElementsByName("ch_u").item(x).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`